# pactl load-module module-sine ====> Failure: No such entity

Tags: pulseaudio

The sound is working perfectly, just this failure when I try to output a sine.

The whole question is in the title. I am on garuda linux which is a flavor of arch. I guess I need to add a package, but which one ?

Also, how can I detect this failure ?

```
pactl list modules
```

lists many things.

Comment: Is `pulseaudio` even installed?  Using the [Arch Package Manifest](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/pulseaudio/files/) as a guide shows that `module-sine` is included in the install.

Comment: I assumed pactl being present meant pulseaudio was on. Apart from this command line, I have sound in every application I've tried. pactl list returns many things

Comment: `pactl` is part of `libpulse` not `pulseaudio`...

Comment: Well, `pulseaudio` may have been replaced with [pipewire](https://pipewire.org/) so you may be hearing audio through that and not `pulseaudio`.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation, I will look now for a way to generate a sine sound with pipewire.